# Android ICS build fails with error 41

Tags: java, android, build, compiler-errors

I tried to build Android ICS on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. All was fine, until ubuntu installed next update for Java.

After this, build fails with error 41:

```
    out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android_stubs_current_intermediates/src/java/util/PropertyPermission.java:2: java.util.PropertyPermission is not abstract and does not override abstract method hashCode() in java.security.Permission
public final class PropertyPermission
             ^
out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android_stubs_current_intermediates/src/java/util/logging/LoggingPermission.java:2: java.util.logging.LoggingPermission is not abstract and does not override abstract method hashCode() in java.security.Permission
public final class LoggingPermission
             ^
out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android_stubs_current_intermediates/src/javax/net/ssl/SSLPermission.java:2: javax.net.ssl.SSLPermission is not abstract and does not override abstract method hashCode() in java.security.Permission
public final class SSLPermission
             ^
out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android_stubs_current_intermediates/src/javax/security/auth/AuthPermission.java:2: javax.security.auth.AuthPermission is not abstract and does not override abstract method hashCode() in java.security.Permission
public final class AuthPermission
             ^
out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android_stubs_current_intermediates/src/javax/security/auth/PrivateCredentialPermission.java:2: javax.security.auth.PrivateCredentialPermission is not abstract and does not override abstract method hashCode() in java.security.Permission
public final class PrivateCredentialPermission
             ^
out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android_stubs_current_intermediates/src/org/apache/http/impl/conn/tsccm/BasicPoolEntryRef.java:5: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
found   : java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue
required: java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue<? super org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.BasicPoolEntry>
public  BasicPoolEntryRef(org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.BasicPoolEntry entry, java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue<java.lang.Object> queue) { super(null,(java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)null); throw new RuntimeException("Stub!"); }
                                                                                                                                                   ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
111 errors
6 warnings
make: *** [out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android_stubs_current_intermediates/classes.jar] Error 41
```

I searched through net, but found only this tip: http://kimoto.tistory.com/26 and some questions (unanswered) in mailing lists.

Unfortunately, it didn't help for me.
My `JAVA_HOME` points to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun`  which is symlink to `jdk1.6.0_30`.
So looks like I now used latest version of Java.

Comment: it might also be good to ask this on http://forum.xda-developers.com Though Java is on version 7 (or jdk1.7): http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7u2-download-1377129.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, resolution was to use open-jdk instead of jdk. It helped to me.

Comment: can you plz tell the device configuration of you machine.ubuntu(10.04 , 64 bit??)

Comment: ok resolved , I found/experimneted that for Nexus S I have to choose lunch full_crespo-user_debug option, I was doing the full_eng(engineering) build.Also inorder to find the correct log for the error I have to use make instead of make -j4.As in the later the logs coming are not the logs from the serial compilation rather parallel compilation by four CPU threads.Also I think it has to be sun6-jdk as recommended by the Android Developer Site and not the open-jdk.I had to remove all the open-jdk components and re-install the sun6-jdk before recompiling evrything.